# After updating to Mac OS X Lion my laptop does not recognize "make" command

Tags: macos

Please, help! Does anybody faced this problem?

```
-bash: make: command not found
```

Comment: duplicate of [Where can I find "make" program for Mac OS X Lion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767481/where-can-i-find-make-program-for-mac-os-x-lion)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`make`, like most developer tools, comes with Xcode. When I upgraded, OSX kept the tools, but if that's not the case for you, just [download and install the Lion version of Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/index.php).

If you need a `gcc` (Lion's Xcode 4.2+ provides only LLVM) and / or you don't want to install the huge Xcode package, use the [osx-gcc-installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer).

Comment: I had old Xcode before updating. I downloaded 4.3 version of Xcode, but make does not work anyway.

Comment: make should be located in `/usr/bin/make`, try that. If it doesn't work, Xcode has not been installed correctly. If it does work, but `make` does not, something's wrong with your PATH. (If you downloaded Xcode from the Mac AppStore, remember that you have to install it after downloading.)

Comment: just to help lion users with this issue. After installing XCode (4.3.3 at time of writing), inside Xcode -> Developer Tools -> More Developer Tools... it takes you to apple developer website where after a few hoops you are able to search for "make" or "gcc" and you can download "Command Line Tools for XCode"

Comment: Latest Xcode (4.3+) does not install command line tools by default. Previous version did. However it is very easy to install them by going Xcode > Preferences then from Downloads tab install Command Line Tools (requires logon with Apple Developer ID)

Comment: Just wanted to mention that after going Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads, you have to click on the Components tab to find Command Line Tools. (For some reason, mine was on Documentation by default and it took me a while to figure it out.)

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you can now download the Mac OSX command line tools as a seperate package without downloading Xcode!

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action (Command Line Tools for Xcode - February 2012)

Answer (score 0):

How I can install gcc 4.7 for Mountain Lion? 4.2 is pretty stable, but 4.7 gives some more speed for Ruby.

I tested it under Ubuntu and it was awesome.