# I installed Xcode 4 on Lion (Mac OS X 10.7.3) but the "make" command is still not found

Tags: xcode, macos, makefile, osx-lion

I recently upgraded from Snow Leopard to Lion and downloaded Xcode from the App Store, but "make" is still not found:

`-bash: make: command not found`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316853/after-updating-to-mac-os-x-lion-my-laptop-does-not-recognize-make-command/9316961

Answer (score 1):

For the latest version of Xcode, the command line tools are not bundled by default. You need to download them from within Xcode.

I believe you can find this under "Preferences > Downloads > Components".

http://holgr.com/blog/2012/02/xcode-4-3-and-homebrew-where-did-my-command-line-tools-go/

Comment: I think you can also use tools from inside the Xcode bundle by using the command xcrun. For example xcrun make.