# Repeated failure when trying to write the Makefile for perl module during install

Tags: perl, circos

I'm trying to install some perl modules as part of the set up for [Circos](http://circos.ca/). I'm installing the modules using cpan in terminal, and while the initial set up seems to go well, all the modules fail during the final step of the install, when the Makefile is being written.

Here's what the error looks like:

```
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Font::TTF
Can't exec "make": No such file or directory at /System/Library/Perl/5.12/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 2026.
MHOSKEN/Font-TTF-1.02.tar.gz
make -- NOT OK
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Running make test
Can't test without successful make
Running make install
Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Failed during this command:
MHOSKEN/Font-TTF-1.02.tar.gz                 : make NO
```

I think the only option might be to manually install the modules instead of using cpan, but I figured it might be worth a shot to put up a question here.

Comment: does installing YAML in cpan do the trick?

Comment: installing YAML failed as well, I think the missing element is the make command, which I haven't got installed. I'm downloading the command line tools from Apple's site right now, hopefully that does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that /System/Library/Perl/5.12/CPAN/Distribution.pm is trying to find your system's "make" command.  Since you're using Mac OS/X is "make" actually installed or do you need to add some developer tools?

Comment: I think that's it. I'm installing the developer tools right now, will update once I've given that a shot.

Answer (score 1):

To further on G. Cito's answer/question:

This old answer might do the trick for you, if you're on Mac OS/X, as the exact same error is thrown in the respective circumstances:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6767528/2352071

Comment: Thanks for the link. It looks like adding the developer tools might do the job.

Comment: Did it do the trick? And have fun with circos, it's great! BTW, the creator of the tool gives very good support via a google-group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/circos-data-visualization

Comment: Another simple way to do it:   search the module on cpan.org , and download it , then put it into circos's lib directory .