# Errors installing johnny-five using npm

Tags: npm, johnny-five

I'm trying to install Johnny Five using npm but I keep getting errors.
This is what I get in the Terminal window.

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:43:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:46:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:57:16
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 12.4.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/nevosegal/GitHub/node_modules/firmata/node_modules/serialport
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.10
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.9.6
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Below is the log file. Anyone?

```
2793 error Error: ENOENT, lstat '/Users/nevosegal/GitHub/node_modules/johnny-five/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/uglify-js/tmp/app.js'
2794 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
2794 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
2794 error or email it to:
2794 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
2795 error System Darwin 12.4.0
2796 error command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "johnny-five"
2797 error cwd /Users/nevosegal/GitHub
2798 error node -v v0.10.10
2799 error npm -v 1.2.25
2800 error path /Users/nevosegal/GitHub/node_modules/johnny-five/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/uglify-js/tmp/app.js
2801 error fstream_path /Users/nevosegal/GitHub/node_modules/johnny-    five/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/uglify-js/tmp/app.js
2802 error fstream_type File
2803 error fstream_class FileWriter
2804 error code ENOENT
2805 error errno 34
2806 error fstream_stack         /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
2806 error fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
2807 verbose exit [ 34, true ]
```

Thanks

Comment: Just a heads up, this is not a Johnny-Five issue. Johnny-Five is for writing software and generally assumes that basic software development tools are installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're on Mac. You need the program `make`. Install XCode from the app store, and then install the package that contains `make`.

[Where can I find "make" program for Mac OS X Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767481/where-can-i-find-make-program-for-mac-os-x-lion)

Comment: As creator of Johnny-Five, I can confirm that this answer is correct.